# Crawling Youtube using selenium in colab

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, web-crawler, google-colaboratory

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

from selenium import webdriver as wb
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = wb.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')     
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = wb.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)

url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%EB%94%A9%EA%B3%A0%EB%AE%A4%EC%A7%81" 
driver.get(url)

body = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'body')
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

I want youtube crawling But the last line of code keeps giving me an error. Can you tell me how should I change the code?

I've searched for selenium here, and followed the results similarly, but my error is not resolved. I need help.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Do you have any reason for not using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to scroll down a page, consider using `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")`

Comment: The send_keys work only on forms or when there's an input available. Selenium cannot press PAGE_DOWN on the body like that. You don't need to scroll down. Just click whatever video you want to by finding its element. You don't need to visibly see the thumbnails